# open layers 3 how to draw a polygon programmatically?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

How to draw a polygon use open layer 3 programmatically?

i have a json array coordinate:

```
[
        {
            "lng": 106.972534,
            "lat": -6.147714
        },
        {
            "lng": 106.972519,
            "lat": -6.133398
        },
        {
            "lng": 106.972496,
            "lat": -6.105892
        }
]
```

and now i want to draw it on map use open layers.
how to do it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to use the `ol.geom.Polygon` constructor. That constructor expects an array of rings, each ring being an array of coordinates.

In your case this is how you will create the polygon (this assumes your array of `lng` `lat` pairs is named `a`):

```js
// A ring must be closed, that is its last coordinate
// should be the same as its first coordinate.
var ring = [
  [a[0].lng, a[0].lat], [a[1].lng, a[1].lat],
  [a[2].lng, a[2].lat], [a[0].lng, a[0].lat]
];

// A polygon is an array of rings, the first ring is
// the exterior ring, the others are the interior rings.
// In your case there is one ring only.
var polygon = new ol.geom.Polygon([ring]);
```

Now if you want to display this polygon in a map with a view whose projection is Web Mercator (`EPSG:3857`) you will need to transform the polygon from `EPSG:4326` to `EPSG:3857`:

```js
polygon.transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
```

And to actually display the polygon you need to wrap it in a feature object, and add it to a vector layer (a vector source really, see below), which you add to the map as any other layer:

```js
// Create feature with polygon.
var feature = new ol.Feature(polygon);

// Create vector source and the feature to it.
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector();
vectorSource.addFeature(feature);

// Create vector layer attached to the vector source.
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource
});

// Add the vector layer to the map.
map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
```

Comment: Quick note: With OL3.5 please use .applyTransform(ol.proj.getTransform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')) on the ol.geom.Polygon.