# OpenLayers 3 doesn't draw the polygon

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I am using OpenLayers 3 and I am trying to draw a polygon using given coordinates, but the polygon is not drawn. Here is what I've tried:

```
var source = new ol.source.Vector();

var ring = [
 [3139880.24789847, 5961935.332187176], [3179627.5026067616, 5972025.01992082],
 [3146606.706387566, 5927997.291628557], [3186353.9610958574, 5939615.719927904]];

draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    source: source,
    type: 'Polygon',
    geometryFunction: ring,
});

draw.on('drawend', function (e) {
    var id = guid();
    e.feature.featureID = id;
    e.feature.setProperties({
        'id': id,
        'name': 'Polygon',
        'description': 'Some values'
    })
    map.removeInteraction(draw);
});
map.addInteraction(draw);
```

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27210362/open-layers-3-how-to-draw-a-polygon-programmically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have the coordinates, I don't think `ol.interaction.Draw()` is suitable. Draw is for cases where the user is able to draw on the map.

Just use a vector layer and add it to the map like so:

```
var feature = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Polygon(coordinates)
});

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        features: [ feature ]
    })
});

map.add(vectorLayer);
```